# Django Server Static files

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I am trying to use the following code to link to the correct image based on the rating. However the server interprets as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/rating-%7B%7Bfeedback.reception_courtesy%7D%7D.gif` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/rating-1.gif`

```
<img src="{% static 'images/rating-{{feedback.reception_courtesy}}.gif' %}" alt="My image"/>
```

I am not sure where I am running wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that variables are not interpolated within the url parameter of `{% static 'url' %}`, so `{{feedback.reception_courtesy}}` is taken literally.

Do it like this:

```
<img src="{% static 'images' %}/rating-{{feedback.reception_courtesy}}.gif" alt="My image"/>
```

This works fine because the variable is now outside of `{% static ... %}`, and because `{% static 'one/two/three' %}` is equivalent to `{% static 'one/two' %}/three`